# bash create many directories if it doesn't exist over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, directory

I want to create on a remote server2 many directories that already exist on the server1.
My script on the server1:

```
LOG_DIR="/opt/server1/service/logs/"
DEST_HOST="server2"
DEST_USER="logger"
DEST_DIR="/volumes/storage/server1"

LISTEN_DIR=$(find $LOG_DIR -type d | tr '\n' ' ')

ssh $DEST_USER@$DEST_HOST " for Y in $LISTEN_DIR
                do
                    if [ ! -d  $DEST_DIR$Y ]; then
                        mkdir -p $DEST_DIR$Y;
                    fi
                done"
```

But on the server1 in directory /opt/server1/service/logs/ there are several other directories...
Results of script:

```
[20:00 root@server1:~]# bash -x script.sh
+ LOG_DIR=/opt/server1/service/logs/
+ DEST_HOST=server2
+ DEST_USER=logger
+ DEST_DIR=/volumes/storage/server1
++ find /opt/server1/service/logs/ -type d
++ tr '\n' ' '
+ LISTEN_DIR='/opt/server1/service/logs/ /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.settlement.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/com.springsource.server.repository.hosted-2.0.0.RELEASE /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.xml2titp.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.mportal.ws.oracle-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/access /opt/server1/service/logs/com.springsource.server.admin.web-2.0.0.RELEASE /opt/server1/service/logs/org.flex.web.plan-2 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.admin.host-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.tickets.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.apijson.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/apool_xyz.plan-2 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.json2titp.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/server1 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.apijson.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.flex.web.plan-2-org.service-com.flex.bundle.main-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.xyzsettlement.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.host-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/wrapper '
+ ssh logger@server2 'IFS_OLD=  

                for Y in /opt/server1/service/logs/ /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.settlement.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/com.springsource.server.repository.hosted-2.0.0.RELEASE /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.xml2titp.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.mportal.ws.oracle-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/access /opt/server1/service/logs/com.springsource.server.admin.web-2.0.0.RELEASE /opt/server1/service/logs/org.flex.web.plan-2 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.admin.host-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.tickets.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.apijson.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/apool_xyz.plan-2 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.json2titp.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/server1 /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.apijson.host.ui-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.flex.web.plan-2-org.service-com.flex.bundle.main-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.xyzsettlement.ws-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/org.service-com.host-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT /opt/server1/service/logs/wrapper  
                do
                    if [ ! -d  /volumes/storage/server1 ]
                    then
                        mkdir -p /volumes/storage/server1;
                    fi;
                done;'
```

Comment: The problem is that you have double quotes surrounding your ssh command, the `$Y` is expanded "locally" directly when you do the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
find local_dir -type d -print0 |
ssh remote 'while IFS="" read -r -d "" a; do mkdir -p "remote_dir/$a"; done'
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner :

```
find local_dir -type d -print0 | ssh remote 'while IFS="" read -r -d "" a; do mkdir -p "remote_dir/$a"; done'
```

### EXPLANATIONS

- `find local_dir -type d` : print all dirs from local_dir so `STDOUT`
- `|` : `Unix pipe` : branch `STDOUT` of the latest command to `STDIN` of the next one
- `ssh remote 'remote_command'` : ssh to a remote server, and execute a command. Single `'` quotes are required to prevent the shell to interpolate `$a` variable
- `while read a; do mkdir -p remote_dir/$a; done` : the remote command, it reads on `STDIN`
- with `mkdir -p`, no need to check existence of any dir

Comment: I do not understand this construction

Comment: Maybe add an explanation for the need of `'` instead of `"`

Comment: and how to organize how to check whether a directory exists of such a case?

Comment: The only serious bug here is that the names should be NUL-delimited -- otherwise, a user who could create a directory named `$'local_dir/ \n/etc/foobar'` could tell the remote script to create a new directory under `/etc`. Use `-print0` on the `find` command, and `while IFS='' read -r -d ''` on the local end, and all should be well.

Comment: Oh -- the lack of double quotes around `remote_dir/$a` is also a serious bug, for reasons will be obvious as soon as one tries to use this with a directory name having spaces.

Comment: Added double quotes, for the rest, OP is free to adapt it a bit if he's paranoid.

Comment: @sputnick I disagree rather strongly that correctly handling the entire domain of possible input is a sign of paranoia. I would, rather, call it "professionalism".